# Voodoo Bizango: Will the Schwalbe Marathon Almotion fit?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, road

I have a Voodoo Bizango mountain bike. I don't do any mountain biking. I use this bike to commute to and from work in West Yorkshire (lots of hills). Once I've lost more weight, I'll invest in a bike more geared for tarmac, but not yet.

Today, I got a puncture. I want to take the opportunity to change the tyres because they are fat and feel very slow on the tarmac.

Will [these fit](https://www.wiggle.co.uk/schwalbe-marathon-almotion-touring-tyre/?lang=en&curr=GBP&dest=1&sku=520753&kpid=520753&utm_source=google&utm_term=&utm_campaign=Shopping%20-%20All%20Products&utm_medium=base&utm_content=mckv%7CsdI9H5xTh_dc%7Cmcrid%7C295270531587%7Cmkw%7C%7Cmmt%7C%7Cmrd%7C520753uk%7Cmslid%7C%7C&mkwid=sdI9H5xTh_dc&pcrid=295270531587&prd=520753uk&pgrid=60973737802&ptaid=pla-522417751624&gclid=Cj0KCQiAzePjBRCRARIsAGkrSm6xc6o69wnCIMUijbHpbnu_qiq9SD4oa01GCgzznh8TZI9O0x9AETkaAkElEALw_wcB)? How do you find that out? I don't want to buy it and then return it when I find out it doesn't fit.

Here is an image of the current tyres:

[image]

Comment: What are your current tires? There should be size printed on a sidewall.

Comment: Added image. It says 29 x 2.25, but not sure what those values mean.

Comment: I'm sure we already have a generic "Will this tyre fit my wheels?" question but I can't find it. Anyone?

Comment: Do store your current tyres for future use - some day you might end up with a more road bike for normal use, and may want to use this bike for more winter riding, or some offroad or whatever.  Lay them flat, with nothing heavy on top.  Out of extremes of heat and sunlight ideally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the new tire will fit.

When checking the tire fit, see what's already on, it's generally safe to assume that narrower products will be good to go. Your current tire is marked as 2.25 inches wide, so a narrower 2 inch would be OK.

There are cases where you have to take into account various factors like rim width, bottom bracket height, amount of travel, crankarm length, frame clearance, but not in your case.

> change the tyres because they are fat and feel very slow on the
>   tarmac.

Feeling slow does not necessary mean going slower. But hey, it's up to you to decide what to put onto rims.

Comment: A _much_ narrower tyre probably won't work. But 2.25in to 2in isn't a big change.

Comment: I have another question. What does the `29` signify? The tyres are linked to are `28` will these still fit?

Comment: 29 is "wheel diameter" in inches, which corresponds to 622 (mm) bead seat diameter, also written on your tire. These are two common ways denote rim/tire size. "29" and "28" are generally the same thing and refer to 622mm.